# How to detect order of parallel line segments?

Tags: algorithm, geometry

Suppose more than two (nearly) line segments are given. How can I calculate the position order of them?

Example:[image]

The result I expect from the input

(x_0a,y_0a), (x_0b,y_0b), (x_1a,y_1a), (x_1b,y_1b), ... , (x_4a,y_4a), (x_4b,y_4b)

is

L_0 -> L_4 -> L_2 -> L_1 -> L_3

Comment: There's hardly any programming content here, it's about geometry and coordinates.

Answer (score 4):

Choose arbitrary segment end as base point. For example, (x0a, y0a).

Make vector for this segment (normalization is not needed)

```
v = (x0b,y0b) - (x0a,y0a)
```

Make perpendicular vector

```
n = (-v.y, v.x)
```

Calculate projection value of arbitrary end of every segment on the line, perpendicular to v   (this value is the same for both ends of segment)

```
d(i) = (xia-x0a, yia-y0a)
p(i) = Dot(d(i), n)
```

Sort p(i)

Answer (score 1):

Build linear equation for every segment:

```
Ai*x + Bi*y + Ci = 0, where  
    Ai = y_ib - y_ia
    Bi = x_ia - x_ib
    Ci = -A * x_ia - B * y_ia
```

For every equation substitute `x` with `0`, and find `y`

```
Bi*y + Ci = 0
y = - Ci / Bi
```

Then sort segments by the resultant `y`.

This works when segments are not parallel to the y-axis. If they are parallel to the y-axis, then substitute `y` with `0`, find `x`, and sort by `x`.